# Docker on windows8.1 faild to start

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, containers

i think this error because my docker can't create container....
whats the problem?
`starting docker_web_1 ... done Attaching to docker_web_1 web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader web_1  | Performing system checks... web_1  | web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced). web_1  | November 09, 2022 - 15:29:41`

(server faild to start)

img
[when runing docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjLnW.png)

Comment: Looks like it's running fine, what do you mean by can't run?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.